# Using ClientBootstrap to connect to LocalChannel with an explicit local address

Tags: netty

I'd like to be able to specify an explicit local address when connecting to a LocalChannel server, created with DefaultLocalServerChannelFactory, rather than relying on "Ephemeral".

(The reason for this is that I want to be able to make multiple connections and have the server use the remote addresses to group related connections).

If I adapt the supplied LocalExample class, just changing:

```
ChannelFuture channelFuture = cb.connect(socketAddress);
```

to:

```
ChannelFuture channelFuture = cb.connect(socketAddress, new LocalAddress("C1"));
```

A channel exception (already bound) is thrown because the channel was bound first by the ClientBootstrap and then again by the LocalClientChannelSink which always binds the channel when it is connected:

```
        bind(channel, succeededFuture(channel), new LocalAddress(LocalAddress.EPHEMERAL));
```

If I ignore the exception everything seems to work and the endpoint of the channel does have the non-default local address.

However, I'd prefer to find a way of avoiding the exception if at all possible

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a "bug". Could you open a issue in the bugtracker of netty ?